# How to display marquee in umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I was trying to get the marquee in my website,but the text is not scrolling.
I have used following code in my partial view.(Note:Ignore the square brackets.)

```
[<marquee>Hello</marquee>]
```

Answer (score 2):

First, the marquee tag is deprecated. So don't count on it working in all browsers. Second, if you really want to use it, I believe you should add a behavior="scroll" property to make it scroll.

Comment: No problem! Remember to accept the answer if it answered your question ;-)